# Reference request for texts that give examples of categories and some of their properties

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

I am looking for texts that give examples of categories and some of their distinguishing properties. There could be a section on the category of sets and its properties, the category of groups and its properties, the category of finite sets and its properties, the category of topological spaces and its properties, etc. I would love to know if there is such a text out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could make the argument that all category texts by necessity have lots of examples and discuss their properties, but I'm interpreting this question specifically as a request for texts that do a particularly good job of making it easy to see a large body of examples and their properties.

My recollection of a really large indexing of categories is the one in the back of

> Herrlich, Horst, and George E. Strecker. Abstract and concrete categories: the joy of cats. Wiley, 1990.

There must be at least 100 categories named, and they all have a row full of references to places earlier in the text, no doubt describing various aspects of them.

Comment: This sort of thing would be a good idea for a database-type site of examples.  I have such a site [for rings](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/). It would be easy to [adapt the code](https://github.com/rschwiebert/RingApp) to do a site for categories, and I would be happy to help someone to do so, if they're willing to find somewhere to host such a site.